# Как достать строку, которая вызвала Exception python

Tags: python, discord.py

Я пишу бота дискорд и у меня появилась такая проблема: Для того, чтобы обработать задержку на команду `discord.ext.commands.CommandOnCooldown` мне нужен метод `on_command_error`, но он работает не с конкретной ошибкой, а со всеми сразу из за чего, когда приходит другая(настоящая) ошибка она тоже попадает в `on_command_error` в виде **Exception** и я не могу понять что её вызвало, так как получаю только текст. Есть ли способ как-то из объекта **Exception** достать информацию о строке, которая его вызвала. Пока что мой код выглядит так:

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_command_error(self, ctx, error: Exception):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        await self.error_message(ctx, f'This command is on cooldown, you can use it in {round(error.retry_after, 2)}')
    else:
        print(error)
```

Comment: А чего-нибудь типа такого не распечатает? `traceback.print_exception(type(error), error, error.__traceback__, file=sys.stderr)`

Comment: Как вариант, но raise error всё-таки проще

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо `print(error)` используйте `raise error`

Это выведет полный текст ошибки, а также список вызовов, который привел к ошибке.

Почитать подробнее можно [здесь](https://pythonz.net/references/named/raise/)

---

А вообще, если вы знаете, какие ошибки нужно исключить заранее, лучше сразу прописать это в начало команды и при ошибке выводить информацию в консоль и вызывать `return`, чтобы преждевременно завершить выполнение функции.

Answer (score 0):

Модуль traceback, но я сомневаюсь, что ты получаешь экземпляр ошибки

Comment: Можешь подсказать метод? Я знаю, что в try exept можно воспользоваться format_exc(), но как в него засунуть Exception?

Comment: В on_command_error приходит <class 'discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError'>